# Finding the Dynkin basis of the weight space.

Tags: lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

I'm trying to understand how Dynkin diagrams work but I'm struggling quite hard.

For example I want to find the Dynkin basis of the weight space. I know that the weight space is the dual space of the root space and that if we take as basis of the root space $\mathcal{B} = \{2\alpha^{(i)}/(\alpha^{(i)}, \alpha^{(i)})\}$ where $\alpha^{(i)}$ are the simple roots. Now the weight space consists of linear maps $\Lambda_{(i)}$ with $\Lambda_{(i)}\left(\frac{2\alpha^{(j)}}{(\alpha^{(j)}, \alpha^{(j)})}\right) = \delta^j_i.$ These are the fundamental weights and form the Dynkin basis of the weight space: $\mathcal{B}^* = \{\Lambda_{(i)} \vert i = 1, \dots, r\}$ where $r$ is the rank of the algebra.

Now I know we can relate the Dynkin diagrams to the Dynkin basis, but I don't really udnerstand how. For example, I want to do this for $G_2$, but I don't know where to start. It seems too much work to first compute all the simple roots...

Comment: What is "the Dynkin basis"? Do you mean a basis of the root system, aka a set of simple roots?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg No, a Dynkin basis is a basis space of the weight space, as I wrote above. It's defined as such in "Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations" from Fuchs and Schweigert on p93.

Comment: I do not understand what "basis space of the weight space" means, and I do not have access to that source. From the example in your question, they seem to be the same as the fundamental weights. Is that the case, or if not, what's the difference?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I wrote a "space" too much, but couldn't edit. I meant to say a "Dynkin basis is a basis of the weight space". Looking online, I think it is a basis of the fundamental weights. So my question is really, how can we get this basis just from looking at the Dynkin diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure where exactly you have difficulties. Maybe an example can help.

How Cartan matrices and root systems can be retrieved from the Dynkin diagram on the example of $G_2\,.$
[image: Dynkin diagram of G_2]

The Dynkin diagram tells us that $\alpha \prec \beta$ and $\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \langle \beta ,\alpha \rangle=3\,.$ The cosine formula tells us, that the angle they enclose is $30°$ but this doesn't matter here. Since the only ways to get an integer product of three are $3\cdot 1 = (-3)\cdot (-1)=3$ we may assume w.l.o.g. and the sign in the theorem of root systems in mind, that $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle = -1$ and $\langle \beta,\alpha\rangle=-3\,.$ This produces the Cartan matrix
$$
G_2\, : \,\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-3&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Next we calculate by linearity in the first argument
\begin{align*}
\alpha - \langle \alpha,\beta\rangle\cdot \beta &= \alpha+\beta \\
\beta - \langle \beta,\alpha \rangle \cdot \alpha &= 3\alpha+\beta \\
(\alpha+\beta)-\langle \alpha+\beta,\alpha\rangle\cdot \alpha &=2\alpha+\beta \\
(3\alpha+\beta)-\langle3\alpha+\beta,\beta \rangle\cdot \beta&=3\alpha+2\beta
\end{align*}
From the decomposition formula
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h}\oplus \sum_{\alpha \in\Phi^+} \mathbb{F}E_\alpha \oplus \sum_{\alpha \in\Phi^-} \mathbb{F}E_\alpha 
$$
we get with a two dimensional Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}=\operatorname{span}\{\,H_\alpha,H_\beta\,\}$ the roots
\begin{align*}
\Phi^+ &= \{\,\alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta,2\alpha+\beta,3\alpha+\beta,3\alpha+2\beta\,\}\\
\Phi^- &= \{\,-\alpha,-\beta,-\alpha-\beta,-2\alpha-\beta,-3\alpha-\beta,-3\alpha-2\beta\,\}\\
\end{align*}
and
$$
G_2 = \operatorname{span}\{\,H_\alpha,H_\beta\,\} \oplus \sum_{\gamma \in \Phi^+\,\cup\, \Phi^-} \mathbb{F}\cdot E_\gamma
$$
[image: all roots of G_2]

If you want to create the weight spaces of arbitrary finite-dimensional representations other than the adjoint, you could look e.g. at the proof of theorem 7.2 for the other simple case $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ in Humphreys's book about Lie algebras and their representations, GTM 9. But I am sure that this example can be found easily on other sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, is there a way to do immediately get the fundamental weights from the diagram or not?

Comment: Do you mean shorter than the 4 equations above? If you want to consider the weights of other representations, then you have to do some representation theory, where Humphreys is a good book to get it from (pages 107-164). I don't know any sources with an algorithm where you fill in the simple Lie algebra, the dimension of the representation, and out comes the eigenspaces, weights, and multiplicities. The Dynkin diagram is primarily a code for the root system of the adjoint representation, i.e. it is a code for the multiplication in a simple Lie algebra.

Comment: I meant without having to calculate the roots. I'm studying notes based on "Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations" from Fuchs and Schweigert. There it's mentioned that the nodes in a Dynkin diagram can be seen as the $i$th fundamental weight $\Lambda_{(i)$. So I'm wondering if we can extract expressions for the weights just from the diagram

Comment: And what would your Dynkin basis be for this example? is it just $\Lambda_{(1)} = (1,0)$ and $\Lambda_{(2)} =(0,1)$?

Comment: I don't know what a Dynkin basis is. The basis of the root space in my example is $\{\alpha ,\beta -\},$ the basis of the dual space of the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}^*$. In the image of the entire root system, it is $\{r,s\}.$ There is a theorem (Freudenthal) that recursively determines the multiplicities. In general, we have $E_\alpha . V_\lambda \subseteq V_{\alpha +\lambda }$ for any $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ and $\alpha \in \Phi$ the  root system. So how can you not consider all roots?

Comment: I defined what a Dynkin basis is in my post. I suppose it is just a basis of the fundamental weights in the weight space. I'm really confused with all of this, so my apologies for asking a lof of (easy/ignorant) questions.

Comment: A Dynkin basis is obviously a basis for the root system. I simply haven't seen it called as such.  It is actually a basis of $\mathfrak{h}^*$, the dual of a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a given semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $V$ be an irreducible, finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$ module with generalized eigenspaces $V_\lambda .$ Then $\mathfrak{h}$ operates diagonally on $V=\oplus V_\lambda,$ and $E_\gamma $ maps $V_\lambda$ to $V_\lambda +\gamma .$ So all which remains to know is the dimensions of $V_\lambda $ which are given by the multiplicities in Freudenthal's formula.

Comment: I'm lost... In our example, what would be an explicit basis of the form $\{\Lambda_{(i)}\}$ where $i$ goes from 1 to the rank of the algebra? Since $G_2$ has rank 2, this should only have two elements right? Or is this basis not remotely interesting at all? I'm confused why the book says it is and that I should use it to prove certain things...

Comment: I am also a bit lost in your question. In order to talk about a weight space, we have to start with a module, i.e. a representation space. You did not mention any. You only talk about roots $\alpha^{(j)}.$ These are the weights of the adjoint representation where we call them roots. $\{\alpha ,\beta \}$ are the basis roots of $G_2$ in my example, $\Phi=\Phi^+\Phi^-$ are all $12$ roots aka weights of the adjoint representation. I described how to get them. Now, if we talk about weights and therewith, say an irreducible, finite-dimensional module $V,$ then it would help to know it. ... (tbc)

Comment: ... (I hate this poor editor window) ... Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra that thus has a Dynkin diagram. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ its Cartan subalgebra, and $V$ an irreducible, finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module. Then $V=\oplus V_\lambda =\oplus_{i=1}^m \Lambda_{(i)},$ the direct sum of the weight spaces $V_\lambda =\Lambda_{(i)}=\{v\in V\,|\,h.v=\lambda(h)\cdot v \forall \,h\in \mathfrak{h}\}.$ $\lambda $ is a weight and $V_\lambda $ its weight space. The weight space consists of ordinary vectors, the weights are linear forms of $\mathfrak{h}.$ All weights are of the form ... (tbc)

Comment: So I wanted to avoid this, but my actual question is a bit different than the one posted here. I wanted to find the solution myself from this post but it seems like I'm getting more confused. I've posted the real question by itself to comply to stack's rules. Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600925/weyl-vector-for-a-2-in-dynkin-basis

Comment: ... $\mu= \lambda -\sum_{i=1}^r k_i \alpha _i$ where $\lambda $ is the highest weight and the $k_i\in \mathbb{N}$ are non-negative integers. What you can read from the Dynkin diagram are the Cartan integers $2\dfrac{(\beta ,\alpha )}{(\alpha ,\alpha )}.$ they determine the geometry of the root system. The weights ($\lambda $) are linear forms, and the weight spaces ($V_\lambda $) are vector spaces.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/lie-algebras-a-walkthrough-the-structures/ Maybe this sheds some light into the subject,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's already way more clear than in my book! So if I'm understanding correctly, the weights are $\lambda$ and not $\Lambda_{(i)}$?

Comment: I get your explanation in the answer itself and the link you provided, however, I still don't understand how we find a basis of the weight space?

Comment: $\mathfrak{h}$ operates diagonally on $V.$ So $V$ splits into a direct sum of submodules of the form $V_\lambda =\{v\in V\,|\,h.v=\lambda (h)v \text{ for all }h\in \mathfrak{h}\}.$ $\mathfrak{h}$ is two-dimensional in out example $G_2,$ i.e. your $r=2.$ Every element $h$ gives another value (e.g. a complex number) $\lambda (h).$ This means $\lambda $ is a function from $\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow \mathbb{C},$ a linear form. It is called a weight of the operation (= representation = module). If the operation is $X.Y=[X,Y]$ then the weights are called roots. ...

Comment: ... the weight space consists of the eigenvectors of the weight.

Comment: That's already quite clear, but I'll have to sit with it to really understand it. Could you also have a look at my linked question?

Comment: How to get to $V=\oplus_{\lambda }V_\lambda $? Well, there is work to do. It is relatively easy for $\mathfrak{sl}(2).$ See the third part of my linked essay (section 6).

Comment: I am sorry, that the word "weight" set me on the module track. Weyl chamber and weight lattice should have been the keywords here.

Answer (score 1):

So there appears to be a little confusion here. I've not heard the term "Dynkin basis" before but you seem to want the fundamental weight basis. But this is directly deductible from the simple root basis which the diagram gives you. Note this is not a basis of the "weight space" but the "weight lattice".

So as you have noted:
To the simple roots we have a natural set of dual elements, the simple coroots. These are the elements $\alpha_i^\vee \in \mathfrak{h}$ such that $\alpha_j(\alpha_i^\vee) = 2\frac{(\alpha_j,\alpha_i)}{(\alpha_i,\alpha_i)}$. Then the fundamental weights are dual to the simple coroots so $\omega_j(\alpha_i^\vee) = \delta^{i,j}$.

In particular we note that they are in 1-to-1 correspondence with the simple roots and they both form bases of $\mathfrak{h}^*$. Indeed we know exactly what the change of basis matrix is: It is the Cartan matrix corresponding to the diagram. You can deduce this from the relations we have just stated.